# Problems installing Maven Sufire Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am learning Maven. I am trying to install Surefire plugin but not able to get the plugin in the Eclipse Marketplace.

I have attached the results image.

Please advice.

[image: Marketplace search results]

Comment: Maven Surefire plugin is a plugin for Maven. Not for Eclipse!

Comment: So in other word you don't need to install something in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.